# grid with single column from array angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I want to display an array [ "text1", "text2", "text3" ] in a grid in angularjs. Here I don't have a field name. How do I do that? and I also need a search in the grid to search items in the column. Grid contains only one column with the list in the array. Sorting should be possible. How do I do it without a field name?

Answer (score 0):

### Display the array:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Search the array:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.input">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="field in fields | filter:search.input">
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Order by:

The most easiest is to order the array using `sort` by javascript:

```
$scope.fields.sort();
```

But you can also do it by using the `orderBy` filter in combination with the `identity` function angular provides:

```
$scope.identity = angular.identity;

<table class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="field in fields | filter:search.input | orderBy:identity">
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Live plunker can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RdltkQNmzdSgED9Vy6n0?p=preview).